# Redux unexpected behaviour | create empty object if not found

Tags: node.js, redux, immutable.js

I am debugging an app, there is an existing redux reducer which sets some data of store object. Now when i dispatch action for this reducer before the relevant object is initialised it still works and create an empty object. This works on our deployment server and do crash on my local machine with correct error that "map is undefined on null". Why is it creating an empty object and not crashing on deployment server and if it is creating an object why is it not assigning the data we pass to it. My reducer is

```
 case ACTIONS.SET_LOCAL_WEIGHTS: {
      const { weight } = action;
      const drafts = fromJS(state.getIn(['draftData', 'rows']));
      const setWeight = drafts.map((row: any) => {
        row.data.weight = weight[row.id].weight;
        return row;
      });

      return state
        .setIn(['draftData', 'rows'], setWeight)
        .setIn(['draftData', 'total'], setWeight.length);
    }
```

It creates: `draftData: {}` when rows and total is also provided. I have tried it on node 15 and 12 for checking any anomaly on map function.

Comment: I'm adding the immutable.js tag since this seems like an immutable-specific issue.  I'm honestly confused by the code but I'm not super familiar with immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I get error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on your code if the initial state doesn't have a property `state.draftData.rows`.  I don't see anywhere where you would be creating an empty object.

The [immutable.js `fromJS` method](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) will create a `List` if called with an `array` from `state.draftData.rows`.  But if it is called with `undefined` then it returns `undefined` instead of a collection with a `.map()` method.

I also don't think that you need to be calling `fromJS` if the `rows` object is never converted `toJS`, but it might depend on your initial state.

This code should work.  It uses the existing `List` from `state` if it exists, or creates an empty `List` otherwise.

```
const drafts = state.getIn(["draftData", "rows"]) ?? fromJS([]);
```

---

The assignment in `row.data.weight = weight[row.id].weight` seems like a mutation of state.

I tried to rewrite this, but it seems strange to me that your code doesn't do anything with the weights in the payload unless their index/key matches one that's already in the state.

```
import { fromJS, List, Map } from "immutable";

interface Row {
  data: {
    weight: number;
  };
  id: number;
}

const reducer = (state = Map(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.SET_LOCAL_WEIGHTS: {
      const { weight } = action;

      const drafts: List<Row> =
        state.getIn(["draftData", "rows"]) ?? fromJS([]);
      const setWeight = drafts.reduce(
        (next, row, index) =>
          next.setIn([index, "data", "weight"], weight[row.id]?.weight),
        drafts
      );

      return state
        .setIn(["draftData", "rows"], setWeight)
        .setIn(["draftData", "total"], setWeight.size);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```